What Is meant by a Slave Women Of A Muslim Bore Children of Harbi Due to Being Captured But Becomes Free Upon Regain of Muslim Control?
Is a slave woman of Muslim who is captured by Harbi and gives birth to children due to being captured by them considered free if Muslims regain defeat the harbis and take control?

أمة مسلمة سبيت فوطئها حربي
.٢١٥٨. ولو أن أمة مسلمة سباها أهل الحرب فوطئها الحربي ثم ظهر المسلمون
على الدار فالأمة وأولادها أحرار لأنها صارت أم ولد الحربي

Source - عُيُون الْمَسَائِل
Is this position even in Hanbali Madhab?
